# How to download several images from a site?

Tags: jquery, html, download, hover, extract

I am trying to download over 100 photos from my clients current site. Problem is they are used as .hover attributes so anything I try with Outwit or other file extractors doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to access this images without download them one by one? Thanks in advance!

```
<a href="/Path_To_Doc/F9-002_word.doc" target="_blank"
class="tip" rel="/employee/path/images/F-Vacation-Wht_thumb.jpg"
title="">Version 1</a>,
```

Comment: Is the path to the image in the `rel` attribute of the `a`?

Comment: There are add-ons/extensions for firefox and chrome that can download an entire page of images for you ;)

Comment: Hey - please see: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-downloader/cnpniohnfphhjihaiiggeabnkjhpaldj

Comment: @geedubb Yes, it is in the rel attribute.

Comment: Is this even programming related?